# Private Go Ethereum client (geth) in Red Hat Linux for all nodes consistently High CPU usage > 38.5% to 70% with no transactions

Tags: quorum

I run multiple quorum nodes i.e. Go Ethereum client (geth) in Red Hat Linux. all nodes consistently report High CPU usage > 38.5% to 70% for geth process despite no transactions are submitted to Geth.

Am using Geth 1.7.2. 2 cpu 4 cores.

Any similar encounters with high cpu usage for quorum?

Comment: Are you mining from node ?